# Список превращается в int

Tags: python, list

```
print("вас приветствует ""Нахождение НОК 2ух чисел")
x = input("введите 1ое число")
y = input("введите 2ое число")
# z = x/z and y/z no %
r = list()
for r in range(1000):
    if r % int(x) and r % int(y) == 0:
        list(r).append(r)
        print(r)
```

Пишет, что `r` это не список.

Comment: `for r in range(1000):` - `r` стал не список.

Comment: *НОК* обычно вычисляется через *НОД*, перебор не нужен.

Comment: `r % int(x) and r % int(y) == 0` - на слух условие воспринимается замечательно, но это не Питон. На питоне нельзя сказать "а и б равны нулю", но можно сказать "а равно нулю и б равно нулю".

Comment: `list(r).append(r)` работает но ничего не делает.

Comment: Кажется, вы пропустили несколько глав в учебнике. Так дела не делаются.

Comment: Какие главы вы имеете ввиду?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так:

```
print("вас приветствует ""Нахождение НОК 2ух чисел")
x = input("введите 1ое число")
y = input("введите 2ое число")
# z = x/z and y/z no %
res = []
for r in range(1000):
    if r % int(x)==0 and r % int(y) == 0:
        res.append(r)
print(res)
```

Comment: Конечно огромное спасибо, но мне было лень писать свой код и я просто взял скрипт с инета. Я на питоне только 3ий день и хотел написать сам.

Answer (score 1):

> Пишет, что `r` это не список.

К сожалению, он когда-то и **был** списком, но уже нет:

У вас в переменной `r`

- **сначала** был пустой список, вы его создали и присвоили командой  `r = list()`,
- но **затем** вы превратили **ту же самую переменную** в переменную типа `int` (целое число) командой  `for r in range(1000):`.

Вы, вероятно, хотели применить **разные** имена — одно для **списка**, другое для **числа** (переменной цикла `for`).

Например, так — я заменил первое `r` на `common_multipliers`:

```
common_multipliers = list()                         # или короче common_multipliers = []
for r in range(1000):
    if r % int(x) == 0 and r % int(y) == 0:         # здесь я исправил ошибку
        common_multipliers.append(r)                # не надо list(common_multipliers)
        print(r)
```